# R importing and exporting csv files (Excel)

Tags: r, excel, csv

This might be a noob question but I have a problem with exporting and importing a CSV.

I export a CSV with values (i.e. 300425.25). When I open this in Excel it is all comma delimited, as expected. When I hit Data To Columns I everytime changes my values to 300425,25 (I have tried all different combinations of decimal seperator in Advanced). This is excellent to work with in Excel but import this back into R I'm stuck with comma before the decimals, which in turn is unusable with the rest of my R code.

I never had this problem with the export of .CSV until I recently cleaned my computer and had a fresh install. I suspect it might be in R studio settings or Excel.

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess it's a setting in your Excel export. To check this, look at a few rows of the Excel-saved file in a text-reading program -- e.g., `head -10 whats.csv` at the commandline.

Comment: Could this be an Excel formatting issue? I'm thinking that Excel may be set to display numbers with a European format (with commas as decimals).

Comment: See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-HP001230245.aspx) for how to change this behaviour in Excel. Basically: Excel Options -> Advanced -> Editing -> Decimal separator.

Comment: When importing into R, you can also set what the decimal separator is.

Comment: Thanks @nickflees it was as I suspected an easy solution which I was to lazy to fix myself. Got it all fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it with the following code. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

y <- rnorm(2)
x <- rnorm(2)
df <- data.frame(y, x)
write.table(df, file = "D:\\test_File_1.csv",
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

path_CSV_File1 <- "D:\\test_File_1.csv"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlApp[["UseSystemSeparators"]] <- FALSE 
xlApp[["DecimalSeparator"]] <- "."
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_CSV_File1)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

rngAll <- Sheets[[1]]$Range("A1:A2")
rngAll$TextToColumns(DataType = 1, Comma = TRUE, DecimalSeparator = ".", TextQualifier = -4142)

xlWbk$SaveAs("D:\\test_File_1_Mod.csv")
xlWbk$Close()
```

The content of the file test_File_1.csv is

```
2.5392366197081,0.78545887144188
-0.623517357751695,0.205786046412415
```

The content of the file test_File_1_Mod.csv is

```
2.53923662;0.785458871
-0.623517358;0.205786046
```